# best pdf compression technique?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

what is the best way to compress pdf without losing quality to half of it's size. I have used ghostscript already but I am not satisfied with the result. Is there any other way to compress it?

Comment: PDF files are, generally, already compressed. Given the complex nature of PDF files, there is no simple answer to your question. Note that questions on the lines of 'what software should I use' are generally considered off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you have a specific question, ask that, don't ask for general reccomendations. Oh, and Ghostscript isn't intended to compress PDF files, nor does it do so.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably won't be able to compress any PDF to half of its size.

BUT

There are some operations that can reduce size of your PDF. Sometimes these operations yield very good results.

So here they are:

- Remove unused objects from PDF
- Replace indirect objects with direct ones (were applicable)
- Use object streams
- Use cross-reference streams
- Compress streams
- Use absolute minimum of whitespace chars

There are even more operations. But they are no as safe as the above ones. They are lossy, so please think twice before applying them.

- Remove metadata or some of metadata.
- Remove structure information
- Un-embed fonts (remove font bytes from PDF)

All of the above can be done with help of [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) (disclaimer: I work for the company).

You probably can use an other library for this. The library should provide corresponding APIs or give access to inner structure of PDF.